# writing xpath for getting a row in a table

Tags: html, xpath

If I write the XPath for a row in a table which is expandable, like each row is expandable on the table. it has a dropdown. if I click on the dropdown of the row, I get to see some stuff inside it.

if I want to write XPath for the body inside the dropdown. ex: for the second row, I get it by writing the XPath:

//div[@class=‘react-bs-container-body’]//tbody/tr[2]

If i write the  following xpath :

//div[@class=‘react-bs-container-body’]//tbody/tr[td[@tabindex="7"]]

where I am trying to access the same thing by giving the attribute of the column which is unique. Xpath should give me the body inside the dropdown.

but this is not happening. The second case won't work. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Show please your html

Comment: show html and use single quotes here `@tabindex="7"` - > `@tabindex= '7'`

Comment: i am actually using a bootstraptable , react-bootstrap-tag. code is:

Comment: bootstrapTableNoExpand() {
    return (
      <BootstrapTable
        ref="BSTable"
        data={this.currentPageTicketsData}
        hover
        condensed
        pagination
        options={{
          clearSearch: true,
          paginationSize: 2,

Comment: prePage: 'Prev',
          nextPage: 'Next',
          withFirstAndLast: false,
          sizePerPageList: [10, 25, 50],
          page: this.data.currentPage,
          onPageChange: this.onPageChange,
          onSizePerPageList: this.onSizePerPageList,
          sizePerPage: this.sizePerPage,
          onSortChange: this.onSortChange
        }}
        trClassName={this.trClassFormat}
        remote={true}
        fetchInfo={{ dataTotalSize: this.data.totalDataSize }}
      >
        {this.drawTable()}
      </BootstrapTable>
    );
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath with single quotations,

```
//div[@class=‘react-bs-container-body’]//tbody/tr[td[@tabindex='7']]
```

Also, you can try with the below xpath as well

```
//div[@class=‘react-bs-container-body’]//tbody/tr[td[7]]
```